# Python Subprocess.Popen or os.popen

Tags: python, bash

hi I want to run a bash command in my script to process a file with ffmpeg, I am struggling to get it to work in subprocess or os

I build my command from variables elsewhere in the script and the resulting string is a legit ffmpeg call:

```
fcommand=(f'/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i   {inputf}  -b:a  128K -vn  {output_directory}{youtube_id}.mp3')

Print(fcommand)  result: /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i   /media/pi/VDRIVE/uploaded/gf23_pmc-speakers.mp4  -b:a  128K -vn  /media/pi/VDRIVE/audio/EN6_KfsEtdM.mp3

os.popen(fcommand)
```

This works, sorta. - eg I can see the output from FFmpeg on the shell I am running my parent python script with (python3 myscript.py)

However, the parent python script just pauses and doesnt do anything further.
So I tried:

```
subprocess.Popen(fcommand)
```

But now I get the python error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg -i   /media/pi/VDRIVE/uploaded/gf23_pmc-speakers.mp4  -b:a  128K -vn  /media/pi/VDRIVE/audio/EN6_KfsEtdM.mp3': 'ffmpeg -i   /media/pi/VDRIVE/uploaded/gf23_pmc-speakers.mp4  -b:a  128K -vn  /media/pi/VDRIVE/audio/EN6_KfsEtdM.mp3'
```

My aim is to have the Python script run, make the file from FFMPEG input then move on to another step in the script.
Bashing my head against the wall here...

Comment: subprocess.Popen expects a list of strings for non-shell calls and a string for shell calls. Try adding shell=True to the subprocess.Popen command. `subprocess.Popen(fcommand, shell=True)`

Comment: Great that works, though it doesn't wait until complete for the next step in the pythons script, is there a way to ensure that?

Comment: process = subprocess.Popen(fcommand, shell=True) then process.communicate()

Comment: Oh nice one! sorted.